# want to get actual path of image or video while using file picker or image picker in flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, dart

i want to import images or video in my flutter app and then want to delete or original files from gallery after importing into my flutter app the problem i'm facing right now i'm using image picker and file picker package they provide me temp or cache path of image not original so wont be able to delete original image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by using a package named [`photo_manager`](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_manager); you can use this package with the following code to delete images and video from your device gallery folder:

```
final List<String> result = await PhotoManager.editor.deleteWithIds([entity.id]);
```

The deleted `id` will be returned; if it fails, an empty array will be returned.